# best way to record local modifications to an application's configuration files

Tags: git

I often install applications in Linux which don't come in package form but rather one just downloads a tarball, unpacks it, and runs the app out of the exploded folder. To adjust the application to my environment I need to modify the default configuration files, perhaps add an odd script of my own  and I would like to have a way to record all these modifications automatically so I can apply them to another environment. Clearly, the modifications can not be reproduced verbatim as things like IP addresses or username need to change from system to system; still an exhaustive  record to what was changed and added would be useful.

My solution is to use a pattern involving **git**. Basically after I explode the tarball I do a **git init** and an initial commit and then I can save to a file the output of **git diff** and a **cat** of all files appearing as new in the **git status -s**.

But I am sure there are more efficient ways. ???

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `git` (or `patch`, if you don't want to depend on `git`) and a bash script where you replace the IP / usernames using some `sed` commands should work. Use `man` followed by the command name to learn about each. In essence, you'll want to store the changes into a git repo (or a patch file to be used with `patch`) and then on the new installation just fetch the changes and run the script to replace the necessary information. Please note that `git` can also produce patch files.